# git error for interactive.diffFilter during interactive stash with diff-so-fancy

Tags: git, diff

My git is [configured to use diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy#with-git) for diff.

I'm getting the following error from git during an interactive stash (`git stash save -p 'some stash name'`):

```
fatal: mismatched output from interactive.diffFilter
hint: Your filter must maintain a one-to-one correspondence
hint: between its input and output lines.
```

Any ideas how to fix this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your best bet is probably just to turn off the fancy mode when using `-p` (`--patch`) modes. Other than that, you'll have to fix any bugs *in* the diff-so-fancy code so that it behaves the way that the `--patch` code needs, and/or make the `--patch` code smart enough to understand the output of `diff-so-fancy`. (Or of course you can just stop using the `--patch` modes entirely.)

Comment: (Idea that might or might not work: set `pager.diff` to `false` while using `--patch` mode. The diff-so-fancy code works by interposing itself as the diff pager; disabling the pager should produce the machine-readable patch output that the `--patch` modes require.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @torek, you put me in the right direction to find the solution 

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution in the end, in case it helps anyone:

- Find your .gitconfig file (mine on my mac was in *~/.gitconfig*)
- Open it in a text editor
- Find the following line:

```
[interactive]
    diffFilter = diff-so-fancy
```

- Remove `diffFilter = diff-so-fancy`
- Save

Problem solved.

Comment: Quick way to open the global gitconfig in your chosen editor: `git config --global --edit` (uses `$GIT_EDITOR` or `core.editor` or `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` or default built in, whichever is found first). The idea I was suggesting in the earlier comment, though, is that `git -c pager.diff=false add -p` *might* bypass the filter directly. It might not, depending on what the fancy interactive code does. Another possibility: `git -c interactive.difffilter= add -p` but I'm not sure if the empty value works here.

Comment: Thanks @torek, but I wouldn't want to have to write such a long command every time I add/stash/etc, nor would I want to have to create an alias for it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is described on GitHub [here](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy/issues/35).

TL;DR:
Use the `--patch` argument as follows:

```
[interactive]
    diffFilter = diff-so-fancy --patch
```